# Labels for nested grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, bar-chart, axis

Instead of having the labels for each treatment on the legend, I would like them placed on the x-axis under each bar instead. This is my code which I am quite happy with:

```
fillggp <- ggplot(corn_germ, aes(x=Day, y=PercentGermination, fill = Treatment)) + geom_bar(stat= "identity",position = position_dodge(), colour= "black") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=12, margin = margin(t=10)),axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=12, margin = margin(r = 10)))

fillggp <- fillggp + scale_y_continuous(breaks= pretty_breaks(), limits=c(0, 1.2)) + labs(x ="Day", y = "Percent Germination")
fillggp
```

which produces the plot
[image]

but again, I want the treatment names to occur exactly under their corresponding bar instead of a legend.

I have tried using facet_grid but the resulting graph grouped each day into treatments which is the opposite of what I want

```
fillggp +
  facet_grid(~Treatment, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: Swap `Day` and `Treatment` — ie, map `Treatment` to `x` in `aes()`, then facet by `~Day`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is there a way to rotate the nested text so it doesn't overlap? right now the treatment names are bunched together.